# Code flow visualization software

Tags: c#, call-graph

Is there any tool, free or commercial, that can generate flow visualization graphs for a C# method? It should be able to deal with decision points (maybe represent them as vertices) and with sequential code fragments (maybe represent them as edges). I know there are similar C/C++ and Java related questions, but I'm interested in C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793685/c-call-graph-generation-tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a commercial tool called [visustin](http://www.aivosto.com/visustin.html). It is capable of generating flow charts in 31 programming languages. You can get the demo version [here](http://www.aivosto.com/shareware/visus502.zip).