# Is there a way to know that a funciton calls other functions?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to analyze that a function calls other functions or uses which variables in C#? For instance，

```
class Test
{
    public int a;
    public void function1()
    {
        a = 1;
        function2();
    }

    public void function1()
    {
        function2();
    }
}
```

So how to know the `function1` uses `a` and calls the `function2`?

Comment: static or runtime analysis? Do you mean field instead of variable? What's your purpose, debugging or code analysis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Application to show all dependencies between functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594018/c-sharp-application-to-show-all-dependencies-between-functions)

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: I want to group the functions in order to implement parallel

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use StackTrace class to analyse the call stack for function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps