# Application functions and objects diagram

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, diagram

I've started editing a big WPF(C#) application project and I was wondering if its possible to have a general diagram or schematic of application as a whole which shows objects, functions and their sequence. is there any application to do this? or does visual studio have any option to do this?

I have tried sequence diagram of visual studio but it shows detail of one function and it calls.but i want something more general and when I needed detail on something just by clicking it go through it and see more detail.

any sort of clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the project in solution explorer -> View -> View Class Diagram?

I'm not sure whether this feature is tied to specific versions of visual studio.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/793685/945456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an option in Visual Studio to generate UML diagram representation for your complete C# code. But, you should be using Visula Studio Ultimate. UML class diagram can be created in the Architecture section.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx) have detailed information.

If you dont have Visual Studio Ultimate, use [Nclass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/index.html). [Nclass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a free tool to easily create UML class diagrams from C# code. The UI looks much like class diagrams in visual Studio and it even has diagram to source code generation feature.

Comment: thanks @Mahesh4b7 it was so great. but i have a problem . when I want to see details. the diagram get so big and visual studio crashes out of the blue. is there any other solution?

Comment: Hi MGol, I am glad that my answer helped you. Yes, I agree that the ability of visual studio to display your gigantic code base is limited by your system RAM and processing capabilities. I suggest you better run it on a server or simply use Nclass for that pupose. Happy coding!